# Understanding big theta

Tags: complexity-theory

Consider the function `f(n)=(e^(n^2))/log(n)`, I need to find a function `g(n)` such that that is  `f(n)=θ(g(n))`.

So I understand that you can multiply constant to f(n) and the resulting function is always big theta of f(n), but I'm wondering is there another function that does the trick?

Comment: Is that (e^(n^2)) / log n, or is that e^((n^2) / log n)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the context of this question? Will any function g work? Couldn't you just pick g = f?

Comment: Where can I find a complete list of class representative of equivalence classes of functions where two function are equivalent if they are big theta of each other?

Comment: I don't believe that such a list exists, sorry! But the function you have here would be a good example of a representative of its own class; this doesn't simplify to anything that's "obviously" better. (Though you could write 1 / log x = (log x)^{-1} = e^{-log log x} and rewrite the entire expression as e^{n^2 - log log n}, but I'm not sure that's any clearer.)